# How to purge massive data from cassandra when node size is limited

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster (with cassandra v3.11.11) with 3 data centers with replication factor 3. Each node has 800GB nvme but one of the data table is taking up 600GB of data. This results in below from `nodetool status`:

```
DataCenter 1:
 node 1: 620GB (used) / 800GB (total)
DataCenter 2:
 node 1: 610GB (used) / 800GB (total)
DataCenter 3:
 node 1: 680GB (used) / 800GB (total)
```

I cannot install another disk to the server and the server does not have internet connection at all for security reasons. The only thing I can do is to put some small files like scripts into it.

ALL cassandra tables are set up with `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` so I end up with very big files ~one single 200GB sstable (full table size 600). Since the cluster is running out of space, I need to free the data which will introduce tombstones. But I have only 120GB of free space left for compaction or garbage collection. That means I can only retain at most 120GB data, and to be safe for the Cassandra process, maybe even less.

I am executed `nodetool cleanup` so I am not sure if there is more room to free.

Is there any way to free 200GB of data from Cassandra? or I can only retain less than 120 GB data?

(if we remove 200GB data, we have 400GB data left, compaction/gc will need 400+680GB data which is bigger than disk space..)

Thank you!

Comment: what Cassandra version?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's 3.11.11

Comment: Do you have the option to add more nodes - even if it is for a short time period?

Comment: Hi Andrew, we can remove one of the nodes, purge all the data on it, and add that one back as a new node. Do you see any option here:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would start with checking if the whole space is occupied by actual data, and not by snapshots - use [nodetool listsnapshots](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/listsnapshots.html) to list them, and [nodetool clearsnapshot](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/clearsnapshot.html) to remove them. Because if you did snapshot for some reason, then after compaction they are occupying the space as original files were removed.

The next step would be to try to cleanup tombstones & deteled data from the small tables using [nodetool garbagecollect](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/nodetool/garbagecollect.html), or `nodetool compact` with `-s` option to split table into files of different size.  For big table I would try to use [nodetool compact](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/sstable/sstablesplit.html) with `--user-defined` option on the individual files (assuming that there will be enough space for them).  As soon as you free > 200Gb, you can [sstablesplit](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/sstable/sstablesplit.html) (**node should be down!**) to split big SSTable into small files (~1-2Gb), so when node starts again, the data will be compacted

Comment: Thank you for answering, today I tried to run `nodetool compact --user-defined xxx` on a certain file, but the tombstones are not removed. (I did this on a 70G file and I should only have 40G data left) Is that the expected behavior? Or do you mean we need to rely on `garbagecollect` command to remove tombstones and we only use `compact` tool with `-s` option to make the files smaller?    The compaction behavior is quite odd, when I just ran compact without defining a certain file, it will remove tombstones..

Comment: during the single file (where is file is 70G) compaction process with `nodetool compact --user-defined xxx`, I notice cassandra is creating a new file with 70G, and remove the old 70G file

Comment: You need to pass several files to user defined compaction because usually deleted data in one file and tombstones in another

Comment: that makes sense, thank you